# wp_enqueue_style is not working in functions.php file

Tags: wordpress

I have this code which i am using for custom theme , but it is not linking css file, can someone let me know, what is wrong in it?

```
function delna_enqueue_style() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'delna_enqueue_style' );
```

Comment: Is the 'handle' ("style") for this stylesheet unique? handle being duplicate could be the potential problem here.

Comment: Have you checked so that directory you pointing to '/css* exists? aslo have you checked you network tab to see if you have any 404? this way you can see if that file exists or not.

Comment: hello @zipkundan - yes handle is unique, it is the only handle in functions.php file

Comment: @zarex360 - yes, the directory pointing exists, as I get URL - http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/delna

Comment: @SuyashPatankar can you try to change it to add_action('init', 'delna_enqueue_style' ) ?

Comment: @zarex360 - it is not working

Comment: @SuyashPatankar have you tried to in your browser go to localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/delna/css/main.css ? so that file can be read by the server, so there is no problem with the permissions. and also change the 'style' to something like  'my-custom-style' 

And is this a child theme or a custom theme from the scratch?

Comment: hello server can read the file, i tried custom-style too, no permission issue

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
function load_parent_stylesheet() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_parent_stylesheet' );
```

Hope it will help for you.

Comment: hello surbhi, i will surely try it next time, as this time the issue is solved, I am not sure what exactly it was, but one of developers solved it. Thank you for your support.